# Multiple selection with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using the following regex to find all the email adresses in my document:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[A-Za-z0-9_]+?\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})
```

It works fine, but now I would like to select them all at once, in order to copy them and paste them in a new document, where I'll have a clean list of email adresses.

[image]

I couldn't find any help on Sublime text website, what are the commands or controls to select/extract multiple parts from a text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or simply click `Find All` on the right of the search box...!